# GTK+ 2 C - enter pressed or button clicked to get text from entry widget

Tags: c, user-interface, gtk, gnome, gtk2

what should I do to print text from entry when enter is pressed or button is clicked with one function? I am asking because when I am clicking at button I get "(PMAF:3592): Gtk-CRITICAL **: IA__gtk_entry_get_text: assertion 'GTK_IS_ENTRY (entry)' failed
(null)"

```
void print_the_entry(GtkWidget *entry, gpointer user_data)
{
    g_print("%s\n", gtk_entry_get_text(user_data));

}

 //search_entry 
  search_entry = gtk_entry_new();
  g_signal_connect_swapped(G_OBJECT(search_entry), "activate", G_CALLBACK(print_the_entry), (gpointer) search_entry);

  gtk_box_pack_start(GTK_BOX(search_and_do_it_h_box), search_entry, FALSE, FALSE, 0);

  //do_it_button
  do_it_button = gtk_button_new_with_label("Do it!");
  gtk_box_pack_start(GTK_BOX(search_and_do_it_h_box), do_it_button, FALSE, FALSE, 0);
  g_signal_connect_swapped(G_OBJECT(do_it_button), "clicked", G_CALLBACK(print_the_entry), (gpointer) search_entry);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you are using a wrong parameter, try:

```
g_print("%s\n", gtk_entry_get_text(GTK_ENTRY(entry)));
```

Comment: Thanks very much, if someone has got warning change "void print_the_entry(GtkWidget *entry, gpointer user_data)" to "void print_the_entry(GtkEntry *entry, gpointer user_data)"

Answer (score 0):

You may need this if you want to hold the values(*entered in entry text*) in a structure of arrays or single array.

```
gtk_entry_set_text(entry1, detail[i].Name);
```

where "detail" is a structure variable and "Name" is a member array of the structure.

Simply in cases of GUI having entry text if you want to see the values on a button click there.